# I am having a problem with a pygame jumping system. Please tell me what's wrong in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

> ```py
> Warning (from warnings module):
>  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\rect 2.py", line 57
>    pygame.draw.rect(win,(0, 0, 255), (x, y, width, height))
> DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using 
> __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
> ```

This is the error I am getting from Shell and below is the code I typed:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

pygame.display.set_caption("nyumph")

x = 50
y = 425
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10

run = True
while run:
pygame.time.delay(100)

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False

keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
    x -= vel
if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - width - vel:
    x += vel

    if not(isJump):
        
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel:
             y -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 500 - height - vel:
             y += vel

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True

        else:
            if jumpCount >= -10:
                neg = 1

                if jumpCount < 0:
                    neg = -1
                y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
                jumpCount -=1

            else:
                    isJump = False
                    jumpCount = 10

win.fill((0, 0, 0))    

pygame.draw.rect(win,(0, 0, 255), (x, y, width, height))
pygame.display.update()
```

pygame.quit()

This code is supposed to display a rectangle and make it jump on pressing the keys. I am not able to understand the error and what is the meaning of it and I also don't know what I'm supposed to do? The jumping is not working somehow. Please help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error, it is a warning. The warning is caused by the fact that the rectangle argument for [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) has to be a tuple with integral values. In your application the coordinates (`x`, `y`) are floating point values.
You can get rid of the warning by rounding the `x` and `y` coordinate to integral values. Use the function [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

<s>`pygame.draw.rect(win,(0, 0, 255), (x, y, width, height))`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.rect(win,(0, 0, 255), (round(x), round(y), width, height))
```

---

The *jumping* does not work in your application because of the wrong [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) in the `if` statements.

See the working example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

pygame.display.set_caption("nyumph")

x = 50
y = 425
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - width - vel:
        x += vel

    #<--| INDENTATION
    if not(isJump):
        
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel:
            y -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 500 - height - vel:
            y += vel

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True

    #<------| INDENTATION
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1

            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            jumpCount -=1

        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))    

    pygame.draw.rect(win,(0, 0, 255), (round(x), round(y), width, height))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```